# Boto upload to S3 not working for certain file types

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, boto

The following code stores uploaded files in S3:

```
def store_in_s3(filename, filecontent, type, modelname, format, manufacturer, adder_id):
    extension = os.path.splitext(filename)[1]
    filename = modelname + "-" + manufacturer + "-" + type + "-" + format + "-" + str(adder_id) + extension
    pathtofile = "Parts/%s" % (filename)
    conn = S3Connection(settings.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, settings.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
    b = conn.create_bucket('mybucket')
    mime = mimetypes.guess_type(filename)[0]
    k = Key(b)
    k.key = "/media/Parts/%s" % (filename)
    k.set_metadata("Content-Type", mime)
    k.set_contents_from_string(filecontent)
    k.set_acl("public-read")
    return pathtofile
```

It works fie for images and text files, but when I try to upload certain file types I get this back and not sure why:

`<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message><StringToSignBytes>50 55 54 0a 66 33 5a 74 6f 74 50 4e 50 4a 62 59 69 6e 67 68 38 38 45 39 45 67 3d 3d 0a 4e 6f 6e 65 0a 57 65 64 2c 20 30 37 20 4e 6f 76 20 32 30 31 32 20 31 36 3a 30 38 3a 35 37 20 47 4d 54 0a 2f 73 6e 61 70 65 64 61 2f 6d 65 64 69 61 2f 43 41 44 50 61 72 74 73 2f 61 64 37 31 31 2d 41 53 44 41 2d 4d 6f 64 65 6c 2d 53 50 49 43 45 2d 31 2e 63 69 72</StringToSignBytes`

Traceback:

```
File "/Users/nb/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/nb/Desktop/spicestore/spices/views.py" in add_model
  577.          new_model.content=store_in_s3(filename, filecontent, type, modelname, format, manufacturer, adder_id)
File "/Users/nb/Desktop/spicestore/store_in_s3.py" in store_in_s3
  24.     k.set_contents_from_string(filecontent)
File "/Users/nb/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/key.py" in set_contents_from_string
  1124.                                         encrypt_key=encrypt_key)
File "/Users/nb/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/key.py" in set_contents_from_file
  994.                            chunked_transfer=chunked_transfer, size=size)
File "/Users/nb/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/key.py" in send_file
  727.                                                    query_args=query_args)
File "/Users/nb/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/connection.py" in make_request
  468.                 override_num_retries=override_num_retries)
File "/Users/nb/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py" in make_request
  910.         return self._mexe(http_request, sender, override_num_retries)
File "/Users/nb/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/connection.py" in _mexe
  810.                                       request.body, request.headers)
File "/Users/nb/Desktop/myenv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto/s3/key.py" in sender
  684.                     response.status, response.reason, body)

Exception Type: S3ResponseError at /spices/add
Exception Value: S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden
```

Comment: What version of boto are you using?

Comment: Neither boto nor S3 care about the type of file or the contents of the file.  So, I suspect the problem is somehow related to either the name of the uploaded key or the metadata associated with it.  Would it be possible to see the full debug log for the request? That might help identify the problem.

Comment: Hey @garnaat you're right -- I renamed the file from .cir to .txt and now it uploads fine. Could it be that `mimetypes` doesn't recognize the .cir extension? I could always hardcode it so that it just changes the extension upon upload/download, but still curious to know why it doesn't like the extension.

Comment: What do you mean by the full debug log? Like the Meta data?

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

`k.set_metadata("Content-Type", mime)`

mime must be None, it looks like s3 doesn't allow  a file's Content-Type to be None. You can remove it, the file will be set to the default content-type in s3.

When using

`mimetypes.guess_type(filename)`

filename should be end with file extension, e.g, www.test.com/1.jpg?code=XXXX 
mimetype can't guess the type, will return None.